# Error when loading a Word 97-2003 .dot to Word 2010

Tags: ms-word, word-processor

I'm trying to load a custom Word 97-2003 (.dot) template in Word 2010.  It loads fine into a new document when double-clicking it, but when I try to add it to an existing document under Templates and Add-ins, I get the error that the document template does not exist.

[image]

I'm running Word 2010 on Windows 7 and I made sure to add it to thedefault template directory **C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates**, so I'm not sure why it's complaining.  Does the fact that it's a legacy.dot file have anything to do with it?  I tried Google, but nothing related to my issue came up other than making sure that the template is in the templates directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was able to get it to load properly.  What I had to do was open up a new document, add the template in the Templates and Add-ins dialog and then open my document.  The Add-in then becomes available.